# Resource Folders in Android Studio Not visible

Tags: android, android-studio

I added several sub directories in the res folder to hold various media resources for my android app in android studio. The folders do not show up in the IDE and are not committed as part of the project using git.

The folders were added to the project both in Finder and in Android Studio via `New Directory` and through Finder as well. The folders do show up in Finder.

How do I properly add these folder to my project?

Comment: Which folder is not visible(Whole Resource or newly added folder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android assets/resources can not handle subdirectories deeper than the standard density-dependent folders.

You have to keep them all in the same folder, and organize them by naming convention (such as *screenname_type_function* aka *settings_btn_logout* for example).

Annoying, especially as iOS handles this great.

Comment: I also come from ios and i do find that to be inconvenient. Which folder is the most appropriate for storing audio files such as mp3?

Comment: Things that are not drawables - images that will be manipulated/drawn etc - such as video, audio, fonts... should go in the /assets folder